# Issue with MenuItem style when having more than one level

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I have a treeview where each item has a context menu. I noticed that if I have more than one level for a menuitem, I will see this style where L1 and L2 have blue borders but their background isn't blue.

Is this expected?

[image: Issue]

My code is just simple..

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="NodeContextMenu">
 <MenuItem Header="L1">
  <MenuItem Header="L2">
   <MenuItem Header="L3"></MenuItem>
  </MenuItem>
 </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected?

Yes. This is the default appearance on Windows 10. Only leafs without child nodes get the blue background.

If you want to change this behaviour you should customize the styles/control templates of the `MenuItem`s. Please refer to MSDN for more information about this.

**Menu Styles and Templates:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm on Windows 8 though.. I guess it's the same for Windows 8?

Comment: Yes, it is the same on Windows 8.